# Error while installing expo-cli with npm and yarn

Tags: react-native, android-studio, expo

I don't know whats's wrong with my system I am trying to setup expo-cli with `yarn global add expo-cli` the expo init projectname doesn't work and its getting me same problem when I am trying to install with `sudo npm install expo-cli --global`?

This is the problem with yarn  https://i.stack.imgur.com/q518S.png
&
This is the problem with npm https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojF0h.png

Answer (score 1):

yarn install worked but directory where yarn puts executables for packages is not added to your `PATH`. If you add it there it should work.

If you want to go with npm, I would strongly recommend to never run `npm install` with `sudo`. Use tools like `nvm` or `volta`. It will install node, npm and all other packages in your home directory, it should solve all issues with permissions without giving access to your entire system.

https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Answer (score 0):

Try avoiding the global npm install with `npx expo-cli`

Alternatively, try `sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm expo-cli` to install the package globally through root. This seems to be a common error with Ubuntu, more information can be found here: https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/591